# Как импортировать динамически

Tags: python, python-3.x

Товарищи знатоки **Python** :)
У меня есть: каталог(относительный) - *library/MDrop/MDrop.py*
Так же основной файл проекта: *project/main.py*

```
#main.py
for x in os.listdir('library/'):
    pluginsNum = pluginsNum + len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(f'library/{x}'), '*.ini')) #считаю кол-во библиотек
    #как в этом месте мне импортировать файл MDrop.py если условно я не знаю как он называется
    #Как я могу использовать переменную X при импорте
```

P.S.:
Вот полное дерево проекта *project/library (main.py)/MDrop/MDrop.py*

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример кода. Файл загружается в spec (спецификацию) с именем handlermod, затем импортируется в переменную ( аналогично import... as mod). и можно обращаться к классу или функции, которые реализуют Ваш плагин.

```
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("handlermod", filename)
    if not spec:
        continue 
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
    Handler = mod.Handler
```

Comment: Выдает данную ошибку: spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("handlermod", filename) NameError: name 'importlib' is not defined

Comment: PS: Я уже выяснил, что нужно **import importlib** прописать Xd
Но появилась такая проблема: pluginsList.append(mod.Handler) 
**AttributeError: module 'handlermod' has no attribute 'Handler'**

Comment: PS: PS: Методом тыка понял, что под **Handler** подразумевался метод в этом плагине.. :)